# looking for a way to create Linq-to-SQL Master-Detail with where in Detail

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a SQL:

```
select * 
from order
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderDetail
 where 
(select count(*) from orderDetail where orderDetail.id=order.id and orderDetail.productName='book')>0
```

how can it implement in LINQ

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your SQL is wrong to start with. This looks more correct:

```
select * 
from order
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderDetail
on (orderDetail.id=order.id and orderDetail.productName='book')
```

Comment: order {id=1}
  orderdertail{id=1, productName='pen'}
  orderdertail{id=1, productName='watch'}
  orderdertail{id=1, productName='cup'}

order {id=2}
  orderdertail{id=1, productName='pen'}
  orderdertail{id=1, productName='book'}
  orderdertail{id=1, productName='cup'}

my sql will select order {id=2}
while orderdertail contains{id=1, productName='book'}

is it clear?